# Prevent mouse from hitting window/screen boundaries in wxPython

Tags: opengl, wxpython, mouseevent, wxwidgets

I'm making a firstperson/camera view using wxPython and an OpenGL pane, and I want to use mouse motion to control the camera angle. To do this I need the mouse movement in x,y per frame.

The way I would do it in other environments would be to move the cursor to the screen centre at the end of each frame, after the movement data has been grabbed - that way it'll never move far away from the center and out of the window bounds.

I found wx.WarpPointer(x,y), which does what I want - except it also sends EVT_MOTION which is, as far as I can tell, identical to real mouse motion. So it just moves the view right back to wherever it started.

Is there some way to differentiate between WarpPointer and user-input mouse events? Or some way to cleverly bind to different functions and StopPropagation on WarpPointer before it can effect this frame's mouse movement?

Alternately, is there another way to do this in wxPython? CaptureMouse seemed good but it just locks the pointer within the window instead of the screen bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag just before calling WarpPointer and in your EVT_MOTION handler check the flag and proceed accordingly and reset the flag.

```
def SomeMethod(self):
    self.isWarping = True
    wx.WarpPointer(x, y)

def OnMotion(self, evt):
    if self.isWarping:
        self.isWarping = False
        do something
    else:
        do something else
```

Comment: I tried this, no luck - the iswarping flag is always false. I think the WarpPointer call might actually run out of sequence, like it's threaded or something. It would be ok if I wanted move mouse > stop moving > warp back, but I need constant movement.

Comment: iswarping always False does not make sense if this flag is set by you.  You defined is as 'self.iswarping', right?

Comment: Yeah; at the end of the OnMotion function bound to evt_motion: self.iswarping=True;self.WarpPointer(0,0);self.iswarping=False - every motion event has iswarping as False. It seems like WarpPointer registers the action for the next frame or something...

Comment: You are just setting/resetting it, you don't check it?  In OnMotion you do the Warp? See edited answer for what I expected.

Comment: No,I've been checking it; no luck. I think WarpPointer is actually moving over more than one frame? http://pastebin.com/kJZQMHZR

Comment: @bonzairob `self.iswarping=True;self.WarpPointer(0,0);self.iswarping=False`.. here you are instantly changing `self.iswarping` to `False`. Some events in `wxPython` call the handler functions with `wx.After`. So you need to set `self.iswarping` to `False` in your `OnMotion` method only like suggested in answer.